# how to redirect to partical page using history object in react-router-dom v6

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I am using "react-router-dom" v6. When i try to redirect to another page using history object i got the following ERROR:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
```

Here is my code:

```
const Search = ({ history }) => {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");

  const searchSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (keyword.trim()) {
      history.push(`/products/${keyword}`);
    } else {
      history.push("/products");
    }
  };
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route exact path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetails />} />
          <Route exact path="/products" element={<Products />} />

          <Route exact path="/search" element={<Search />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `history` object was replaced by a `navigate` function in `react-router-dom` version 6, accessed via the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate) hook.

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const Search = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");

  const searchSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigate(keyword.trim() ? `/products/${keyword}` : "/products");
  };
};
```